# Selenium WebDriver IE6 with enabled proxy issue

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I have some tests created using Selenium WebDriver. When I run them using IE without proxy - it works awesome, but when I am trying to turn on the Proxy (Automatically detect settings) Selenium can't identify objects. I am getting error message: "Unable to find element "

Does anyone else meet the same situation?

Comment: Can you post any details on what you use to enable the proxy please?

Comment: I just enabling proxy using Browser's settings: Tools->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings and selecting Detect Automatically checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at "Automatically detect settings" feature which has socks configuration parameters. Somehow it was blocking some of selenium interactions channel with browser.